# How do I style multiple cells of a datagrid based on the same trigger?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, triggers, styles, converters

I have a simple DataGrid with a column of text and a column with a checkbox, and based on some fairly complicated conditions I want to style the text AND set or disable the checkbox. I can implement the same trigger for both cells but that seems like bloat and unnecessary, I am looking for the most efficient way to do this. It seems like it should be possible, I am just at a complete loss.

```
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Label Name="needToStyleThis" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="Auto">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="needToSetIsChecked"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally achieved with data binding. If you add a `bool` property to your data class, then you can do your *complicated conditions* in the property setters of the class. In the class, you can change any of the property values dependant on any other value easily. Maybe something like this:

```
public string Text
{
    get { return text; }
    set 
    {
        text = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Text");
        IsEnabled = text == "some value" && otherSomeConditions == true;
    }
}
```

Then you could data bind that to the `Checkbox.IsEnabled` property like this:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Name="needToStyleThis" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="Auto">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" ... />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```